# Use SQL data for flot chart with C# and ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, asp.net

I am new to flot charts and more a SQL guy than a C# programmer.  I am attempting to have a bar chart reflect monthly sales.  I can't seem to get my data through to the chart.  I have been searching all over for a direct answer on getting this to work and have had zero luck after 4 days.  Here is what the stored procedure returns:

```
MonthID SoldCount   MonthName
4        101         Apr
8        118         Aug
2        74          Feb
1        74          Jan
7        113         Jul
6        126         Jun
3        114         Mar
5        129         May
9         47         Sep
```

Here is my code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using SkywebReporter.Classes;

namespace SkywebReporter
{
    public partial class DefaultObject : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
        }
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConn"].ConnectionString;
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]//public static web method in code behind
        public static List<PNMACsales> GetData() //int StartRowindex, 
        {
            List<PNMACsales> myResult = new List<PNMACsales>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                //string sqlString = "SelectbyYearTotalProductAssign";
                string sqlString = "PNMAC.procReportSalesCounts";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        PNMACsales obj = new PNMACsales();
                        obj.SoldCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["SoldCount"]);
                        obj.MonthName = rdr["MonthName"].ToString();
                        myResult.Add(obj);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            } 
            return myResult;             
        }      
    }
}
```

This is my JS file Dashboard.js

```
function DrowChart() {
    jQuery("#placeholder").html('');
    var list12 = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DefaultObject.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.map(data.d, function (item) {
                var list = [];
                list.push("'" + item.MonthName + "'");
                list.push(item.SoldCount);
                list12.push(list);
            });
            var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [list12],

                                     );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `Flot Chart` do you mean `Float Chart`..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE http://www.flotcharts.org

Comment: cool .. never heard of it.. guess you learn something new everyday.. :) thanks `Zee Tee`

Comment: You should post your JSON data that you're plot is using.

Comment: Seems like you should post a question on how to work with databases first in .net, then be concerned with how to get your json response to the flotchart. Since without JSON data, flotchart usage is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are successfully getting a response from your GetData() method, you need to serialize the List that you are returning from your GetData() function. This is because JavaScript can't do anything with a C# List. It needs to be converted to a string format (JSON) that JS can recognize.

As some of the comments suggested, adding JSON.Net to your C# project is an easy way to do this.

Once you have installed JSON.Net, you can change the return type of GetData() to string, and do the following:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResult);
```

In your JavaScript, you'll need to parse the serialized list:

```
var list = JSON.parse(data);
```

The list should be parsed as an array of objects, which you can then pass into flot in the format you need.

Comment: I am now getting a response from my GetData()).  Here is the code that is now working.  Do I still need to add serializer here?                                                   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static IEnumerable<procReportSalesCountsResult> jsonData()
    {
        using (OpsDBDataContext dc = new OpsDBDataContext())
        {
            return dc.ReportSalesCounts().ToList();
        }
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with dates in FlotChart, you want return the date in UNIX time stamps multiplied by 1000, by using this ASP code to filter the dates your return to flotchart:

```
DateDiff("s","01/01/1970",MyDate)*1000
```

This gives it to FlotChart how it wants it, so you can use all the date features it offers.  When you do this it will write the dates for you and the month names, etc.

Without seeing the JSON data you're feeding flowchart, it's really not easy to understand where your errors may be, but since you're using dates, this must be one of them.

Comment: The JSON data would be returning from the stored procedure above.  It has MonthID (int), SoldCount (int), MonthName (string).  I can't get the JSON to generate which is part of my issue.  Thank you for responding.  Super frustrated right now.

Comment: You might want to consider creating your JSON object. I've found the package JSON.Net for this useful.

Comment: You can still extract the JSON data the chart is working off (with firebug, etc) and post it here, that's what will help resolve the issue.

Comment: So would I serialize an object or serialize a dataset the way I have my C# code right now? I'm very very new to C# so I appreciate your patience. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Well I don't use the SQL method you do, so not sure on that. But you would create your own c# object, then JSON.Net will serialize it for you, then you can return it and it will be formatted all properly.

Comment: What method do you use to create the object? Again being new to C# I am trying to learn best practices.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you click that link, look in the first example on the right, it shows you how.